# GitLab CI with node.js

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci

I have no experiences with GitLab CI.
So I choose to use node.js (https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/#gitlab-runner) and installed it on my local machine.

I've run `gcr` after the Installation finished successfully.
Than I enter the GitLabCI-URL and my GitLab CI Registration Token.

After this I got a dozen times this message:

```
 gcr info [client] checking for builds... 
 gcr http 404 https://ci.gitlab.com/api/v1/builds/register.json
 gcr info [client] checking for builds... 
 gcr http 404 https://ci.gitlab.com/api/v1/builds/register.json
```

If I enter the above URL in my Browser, the Console give this message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405
>   (Method Not Allowed)

Can anybody help me to got the first Steps with GitLab CI and the node.js connection to it?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but I can tell you that the `405` error you saw from the browser is because the server is expecting a POST request and you are trying to access it using a GET.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Have you registered your runner? There's a difference between registration and runner token...